# how to use ajax in shopping cart session - node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ajax, cart

I want to insert and delete products in my shopping cart without refreshing the page. I'm trying to use ajax in my code but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. For example, this code should insert something in the data field? Please help me in this question

Below it's my ajax code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#cart_id").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var product;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: product,
        url: 'http://localhost:8888/add-to-cart-forward/:id', 
        success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        }
      });
  });
});
```

This it's my node JS code

```
  router.get('/add-to-cart-forward/:id', function (req, res, next) {   
      var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});

      Product.findById(productId, function (err, product) {
          if (err) throw err;
             cart.add(product, product.id);
                req.session.cart = cart;
                console.log(req.session.cart);
              res.render('shop/description', product);
           });
        });
```

Comment: On the function `success: function(response) { console.log(response); }` you should do the DOM changes on the webpage you need looking at the responde you got from the Ajax call.

Comment: i try to do DOM cganges into success function but i just get this message:                                   
                                                                                                                            
message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value ":id" at path "_id" for model "Product"',
  name: 'CastError',
  model: Model { Product }

Comment: Please edit the question, and add the code you placed on the `success` function and the render() function too. Wee need to know what the render returns (JSON code, XML code, plain text code, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alredy done. Its work now. Thanks for attention. I didnt change my node js file, only ajax.        This is my ajax code.

```
$(document).on('click','#cart_id',function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: id,
        url: '/add-to-cart-forward/' + id, 
        success: function() {
          console.log(id)
       }
    });
});
```

I just changed some fields and separated "id". I wish somebody can use it